# Python requests https through Burp. Verify param, default certs path

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

I want to use the Python `requests` library trough Burp without having to set `verify` to `False` and without having to select the certificate to validate.

I want to know what is the default path it uses, so I can store my certificate there without having to set the `verify` param (as it is set to `True`by default).

This is what I have done:

I have exported the Burp certificate and converted the `.der` to `.pem`:

`openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out burp.pem`

Then I can go through Burp like this:

```
proxy = {'https': 'http://<myip>:8080'}

resp = requests.get(url, params=parameters, proxies=proxy, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/burp.pem')
```

or either by:

```
resp = requests.get(url, params=parameters, proxies=proxy, verify=False)
```

But I want to use it without the `verify` parameter.

I thought that the default path for the verified certificates would be `/etc/ssl/certs/` so there is where I placed it, but apparently not.

I have read the requests documentation but I haven't figured out what path should I set it, or if even what I want to do is possible or not.